# MySQL super CPU spike when save / post wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress, apache

I've got a WP database with approx. 10k+ posts.  Everytime a user saves / posts (insert or update query), apache server CPU spikes to 100% and MySQL spikes to 100% CPU usage, eventually crashing.  I'm assuming the culprit here is MySQL, however there are zero errors in the log and there are no relative slow query log.  The wp_posts table is myisam based and not innodb (using full text search).  Could this be a configuration issue with myisam?

Specs:
Wordpress: 3.4.2
Server: Amazon EC2 Small Instance (1.7gb ram, 40% free)

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: need more information: WordPress version & server spec

Comment: @ShivanRaptor added above.

Comment: MyISAM is good at write I/O, thus it is not the culprit of slowness. Did you install a lot plugins that add hooks when posting?

Comment: There are a few plugins installed, but I don't think anything for hook or a push.  Keep in mind that this spike also occurs also occurs when just saving a draft and not actually publicly posting. Primary plugin would include W3 Total Cache.

Comment: I may have just figured out my issue, please stand by.  Might most likely be a plugin.

Comment: Okay so, one of the potential plugs (similar post plugin) I thought it could be was not.  In fact, I went through and enabled / disabled a few plugins, eventually causing SQL to over load once again and crash.

Comment: try to enable Slow Query Log in MySQL if available. Default is OFF and set to 10seconds. Set it to, say, 5 seconds and look into the log

Comment: Tried that, SQL showed nothing for slow query (had it set to 2 seconds too)

Comment: then, do you confirm it is database side issues? or it is web server side / scripting side issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue determined: It was a plugin.  Make sure you always test out your plugins!